# Django using related_name in self.object

Tags: python, django, django-models

I would like to do the following

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

  def has_stock(self):
    """
    Returns True if stock is available or False if not.
    """
    if self.stocks:
          return True
    else:
        return False



class Stock(models.Model):
  code = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name="stocks")
```

When I get a product I want to find out if I have stock. I'm hoping I can use the related name to do this but this does not seem to work, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stocks` is a queryset. You need to actually call some of the queryset methods on it in order to query the related data.

In this case, `self.stocks.exists()` would probably be appropriate.

(Also, for the future, please note that "does not seem to work" is not a helpful thing to say. You should explain exactly what happens, and how that differs from what you expect to happen, along with specifics of any errors.)